# How to use contains with multiple words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just wondering Can i use contains with 2 DataFrames? like grep in R.
When i use merge() or join(), the row makes duplicated. this is for the example

For example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'name':['hayley','jack','may'],'class':['H','M','S']})
```

df1

| id | name | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hayley | H |
| 2 | jack | M |
| 3 | may | S |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'number1':[4,5,6],'name1':['cat','chang','jason'],'class1':['H','H','S']})
```

df2

| id1 | name1 | class1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | cat | H |
| 5 | chang | H |
| 6 | jason | S |

and i want to match df1['class'] and df2['class1']. if the class, class1 rows has same word, concat. if not null.

sorry for my English. i don't really know how to explain it....

this is what i want to make it!!

| id | name | class | id1 | name1 | class1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hayley | H |  |  |  |
| 2 | jack | M |  |  |  |
| 3 | may | S | 6 | json | S |

however, if use merge()

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on='class', right_on='class1', how='left')
```

| id | name | class | id1 | name1 | class1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hayley | H | 4 | cat | H |
| 1 | hayley | H | 4 | chang | H |
| 2 | jack | M |  |  |  |
| 3 | may | S | 6 | json | S |

i want to know how to make that without duplicate. plese help :'(

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove rows with 2 or more `class1` and then use left join:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('class1', keep=False),
               left_on='class',
               right_on='class1', 
               how='left')
print (df)
   id    name class  number1  name1 class1
0   1  hayley     H      NaN    NaN    NaN
1   2    jack     M      NaN    NaN    NaN
2   3     may     S      6.0  jason      S
```

**Details**:

```
print (df2.drop_duplicates('class1', keep=False))
   number1  name1 class1
2        6  jason      S
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean mask and then [**`pandas.DataFrame.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to match only the rows with non duplicates values.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'name':['hayley','jack','may'],'class':['H','M','S']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'number1':[4,5,6],'name1':['cat','chang','jason'],'class1':['H','H','S']})

m = df2.groupby('class1')['number1'].transform('count').eq(1)

out = df1.merge(df2.loc[m], left_on='class', right_on='class1', how='left')
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

```
   id    name class  number1  name1 class1
0   1  hayley     H      NaN    NaN    NaN
1   2    jack     M      NaN    NaN    NaN
2   3     may     S      6.0  jason      S
```

Comment: I did the swap and then it didn't worked. I think there is no other solutions than a left `pandas.DataFrame.merge`. I updated my answer. Thank you jezarel.